# Speakers Stuck at 100%

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, audio-player

I have a Hp-15 laptop from late 2014 and in Lubuntu 17.10, the speakers are stuck at 100%! Good thing the speakers aren't very loud. I don't know what to do to fix this. In terms of drivers, the only thing I get is amd processor microcode. This is even more strange when you consider that a USB enabled guitar amp can be controlled just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! It was actually the microcode I mentioned somehow disabling proper speaker control. Uninstalling the driver makes it work fine.

Comment: Can you **[edit]** this to expand it with details about how you fixed the problem?